# Ubuntu 10.04 and Nvidia Proprietary 96 drivers

Tags: xorg, ubuntu-10.04, nvidia-graphics-card

I am running 10.04 ubuntu, on a totally fresh, but update manager completed install. I've hit the recommended drivers from System > Administration > Hardware Drivers and let it run to install the 96 drivers.

I assume this version is best as I'm using a Geforce 128mb Ti4200 card.

It seems to be a fantastically popular problem, but I'm only getting 640x480 res. I've adjusted the panning to 1024x768, as the max res on my screen (NEC Multisync LCD1550V) and it's all okay, but I don't want to have to pan a 640x480 screen around!

I've tried pretty much all the fixes I can find.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=484680
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

I've also tried the `xrand --addmode S-video 1024x768` which just throws an `unknown output s-video` hmm. I've not had a go with the `cvt` as I'm not sure on all the stats I need for my screen.

I'm so close to closing out my install, with just this one little niggle remaining. I've tried a direct edit of the `xorg.conf` also, with adding a `Modes "1024x768_60"` line in the 'Screen' 'SubSection "Display"' to no avail. Restarting X by swapping to console 1 and executing `/etc/init.d/gdm restart` seems to just do nothing. I've also tried adding a metamode of `1024x768_60 @1024x768` to see if I can dupe the drivers, which didn't work either.

Hopefully I've put down enough info, it's 2am, and frankly I've had enough for tonight! Any help with this would pretty much guarantee you a spot in my all time hall of fame. 
Thanks, appreciated.

Comment: Afterthought, I should mention that I've also tried `gksudo displayconfig-gtk` from Terminal with no success, and that the default 'Monitors' panel is reporting the panning, so a res of 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

Does this article help (too long to reproduce here):
[Ubuntu 9.10, Resolution Issues](http://amateurpc.wordpress.com/2009/11/07/ubuntu-9-10-resolution-issues/)

Refresh rates and sync values also seem to be a common cause of such problems.
85Hz is apparently the correct refresh rate for your card.

Comment: Ah great, I didn't try running nvidia-settings as sudo from terminal, will give this a try!